# android opencv capture just a part of entire camera view

Tags: android, opencv, camera-view

i am a beginner on android.

My question is simple, i need to capture a video frame from my device but i need to capture just a part of the entire camera view. For example, if my camera view display my frame on the entire screen i need to cut half frame to display.

I did this with opencv through image processing (image cropping) but i wanna know if this is possible also specifing the layout parameters. I need know if this is possible because i working with a video frame not with simple image and i need to ease the entire processing.

Thank you for all advices.

Comment: Ok men is incredibile, i searched the solution for almost one week...and now after post this question, i have found the solution at my problem. I just used the layout parameter "translationY" for solve this. However thanks alot you all

Comment: Then you should write an answer for your own question

Comment: Any answers using TranslationY, how you achieved it. It'll be much appreciated.